# SharePoint Ribbon Loading endlessly

Tags: javascript, ribbon

i'm a beginner of SharePoint.I'm using 2010version. Here i'm facing  a problem that the ribbon of my root site is loading endlessly. I could not use the options like  page, Edit,site action etc.. but it works in other sub sites. Give me some suggestion to solve this problem.

Here is my scenario, My root site URL http://xxxx. In this URL the ribbon is not working, but it works in http://xxxx/yyyy.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: Any custom javascript on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Try the loopback check fix:

http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx